# Trying to create a moving smoke stack

Tags: particles

I've got a smoke emitter moving and inside a cylinder collider object that is also moving. My intention is to have the smoke emitting from the cylinder like it's a smoke stack, but for some reason during the movement it just kills all the smoke particles.

As soon as it comes to a stop it emits correctly. Curious what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a gif to demonstrate

https://share.getcloudapp.com/wbueEm4B

[image]

Comment: I think the biggest issue is that you have initial velocity turned really high so as soon as the smoke generates it just kinda shoots off. If you turn off initial velocity or turn it a lot lower and then mess with the other settings (temperature difference, surface), you might get a more desirable outcome.